# Can you implement two results from an IF statement

Tags: matlab, if-statement

Is it possible to somehow to have two outcomes from each `IF` and `ELSEIF`. My example is as follows,
so at the moment my code is:

```
for i=1:(size(y,2))
    if maxind(i) == maxy
         y(:,i) = y(:,i)*100;
    elseif maxind(i) <= maxy/40
        y(:,i) = y(:,i)*40;
    end
end
```

However I would like to record the multiplication coefficients corresponding to each `y(:,i)`.
I would like to do something like this below with my hypothetical code in " ":

```
for i=1:(size(y,2))
    if maxind(i) == maxy
             y(:,i) = y(:,i)*100 "& coeficient(i) = 100";
        elseif maxind(i) <= maxy/40
            y(:,i) = y(:,i)*40 "& coeficient(i) = 100";
        end
end
```

I cant simply repeat this `FOR` after as the `y(:,i)`'s change, I could do it before but it seems a little messy. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not?:

```
for i=1:(size(y,2))
    if maxind(i) == maxy
             y(:,i) = y(:,i)*100 
             coeficient(i) = 100;
             % you can add here as many lines you want...
        elseif maxind(i) <= maxy/40
            y(:,i) = y(:,i)*40  
            coeficient(i) = 40;
            % here also, thats the WHOLE pourpose of the "end"
        end
end
```

Comment: Oh no! This is exactly what I need. I feel silly now. I suspect I have even unwittingly done this before. haha. Many thanks Ander